# How to exec against a loaded splayed table in KDB?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I have a splayed table written to disk via `.Q.dpft[]`.  After load this table using the `\l` system command, I can `select` from this table, e.g., `select column_name from splayed_table where xyz`

However, when I convert `select` to `exec`, I always get the `'nyi` error: *Not yet implemented*.  As a workaround, I use: `first value flip` instead of `exec`

1. I am doing something wrong?
2. Is there a better way?

Note: My KDB+ is `KDB+ 3.3 2016.03.14` (Linux 64-bit).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

exec cannot be used against a splayed table. A more efficient workaround may be to do `exec column_name from select column_name from splayed_table`

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  I did not think of chaining `exec` on `select`!